# What is the difference between creating a passphrase before vs after adding a private key to an ssh-agent?

Tags: encryption, ssh

I am following this tutorial: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

In step 2, Generate an RSA key, the fourth line of the first block of code is the ssh-add command

`ssh-add id_rsa`

The very next step shows a request to create a passphrase.

When I did it, I was prompted for a password immediately after line 3 of the first block of code, which says

`Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]`

Question: should I be prompted for a password before or after the ssh-add id_rsa command?

Appended is my shell log

```
-------------------------------------
Taras-MacBook-Air:~ tlroys$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "tlroys@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/tlroys/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/Users/tlroys/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/tlroys/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/tlroys/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
[REDACTED] tlroys@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|+..              |
------------------------------------
```

Cheers, Tara Roys

PS. My admittedly hazy understanding of ssh tells me that the reason to have a password is to encrypt your private key so that it can't be simply copied and used elsewhere.  In my head, the ssh-add id_rsa command is a cross between a safe and a personal assistant. You stick your keys in the safe, and tell your personal assistant the password once. She then uses that password to decrypt all of your keys as use them on your behalf, but she''s somehow immune to coercion and will tell nobody else what your password is.

It make sense to me that you would create a password to encrypt your keys. You would then give your keys to the personal assistant. You would then tell her the password so that she can use the keys.  She would tell nobody else.

However, the tutorial seems to imply that you create keys that are not encrypted, and then you give them to your personal assistant, who stores them securely, and tells you that you must make up a password in order to use them.

Which is the right mental model?

Update: It appears that if I create a password for the private key when I generate the keypair, the agent needs me to input that passphrase as well.  If I don't create a password, the agent doesn't need me to input a passphrase.  If I input a passphrase, that means it's encrypted and in order to use the key the agent needs to know the passphrase. If the key is not ecncrypted, the agent can use it without asking me anything else.

In short, the github tutorial skipped a vital step by inserting an ssh-add id_rsa command in the middle of the standard creating a keypair workflow. Is this a typo or something I'm missing?  Stay tuned!

UPDATE:  The github tutorial had skipped a step.  I put in a help request to Github, and they emailed me back, saying

> Thanks for pointing this out, and I'm sorry for the confusion. It looks like it's actually a problem with the ordering of the steps in our docs, not with your understanding of SSH:) I've passed this info along to our Docs team to take a look.
>
> The `ssh-add id_rsa` step should come at the end of Step 2, after entering the passphrase. Running that step should prompt you again for your passphrase. That will save your id_rsa identity file to the ssh-agent, and you shouldn't need to reenter your passphrase again.

Comment: Good practice is to encrypt your private keys. This mangles them so that nobody can use them without your passphrase. `ssh-add` is part of `ssh-agent`. `ssh-agent` is a "personal assistant", to use your parlance, who knows your password and your key and decrypts it when you ask so you don't have to type it every time. As far as I know, there's no way to have `ssh-agent` itself encrypt anything. Does that answer your question?